# How to rescrape facebook share page datas

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I have developed a website that contain feeds. When one new feed added, the facebook share working as correctly. The old datas are saved on facebook cache. When I edited ther is no change in share data.

After scraping the page in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ it will clear the old data and place the new edited data on facebook share page.

Any working code in PHP that automatically rescrap the share datas????

My website is http://www.foxdray.com/feeds/ .

I want to share the page www.foxdray.com/feeds/index/posts/?genre=317 , or else any new feed, after editing.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a re-scrape via a simple POST request, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

---

(How to make a POST request with PHP is something easy enough to figure out, f.e. [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) If you are already using the PHP SDK in your project by any chance, that has methods to directly make POST requests to the API as well.)

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.foxdray.com/feeds/index/posts/?genre=322&scrape=true                                                    Like this?????

Comment: No, an _API_ request - those are made against `https://graph.facebook.com` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/